# Translation rules in Hilbert Calculus

Tags: hilbert-calculus

I am trying to prove the fact $A \supset B, A \supset C \vdash A \supset (B \land C)$ in a hilbert-type system. However, I am struggling to find a translation rule for $B \land C$.

Citing from [my textbook](https://lccn.loc.gov/2014044032):

> We introduce other connectives [besides $\supset$] by definition: 
>   $$(D1) \quad(B \land C) \text{ for } \lnot(B\supset \lnot C)$$
>   [...]
>   The meaning of $(D1)$, for example, is that for any [well-formed formulas] $B$ and $C$, "$(B \land C)$" is an abbreviation for "$\lnot(B\supset C)$".

The definition of course makes sense, but how do I cast this into a useable rule for the calculus?

Semantically, it would be correct to conclude that $A \supset \lnot(B \supset \lnot C) \vdash A \supset (B \land C) $ but can I just replace one with the other in the calculus?

Or should I start with a simple rule like $\lnot(B\supset \lnot C) \vdash (B \land C)$ and somehow include that in my proof?

Comment: Hey Rafael, I have deleted my previous answer as it contained mistakes in the deductive rules even after the edit. I will hold off answering any further until I have relearned Hilbert style deductive rules.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the effort :)